# Strange $stateParams behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple application that displays data in a table format. On this table, you can click columns to sort them in ascending/descending order, do searches, etc. I would like the the URL to change when events like these occur, that way if someone is given the URL, they will be presented the information in the same manner.

Currently, when click on a column to sort asc/desc, this gets called:

```
<a ui-sref="name({column:'\''+column+'\'',sort:reverse})">
```

"name" is a state defined here:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('name', {
            url: '/column/:column/desc/:sort/',
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }
]);
```

When the location changes, this is called:

```
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $scope.predicate = toParams.column;
        $scope.reverse = boolVal(toParams.sort);
    });
```

Everything works correctly *after* the page load, however, when I try to get a page to load with parameters initially from the URL, it doesn't work.

```
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, viewConfig) {
        console.log(($location.search()).column);
    });
```

I try using the above method to get the column parameter in the url, but when I console.log, but it returns undefined. Even after the page loads, and the url is changed and everything works, viewContentLoaded *still* logs undefined. Am I doing something incorrectly?

A sample url might look like this: 
www.domain.com/column/'column name'/desc/false/

The table would then be sorted on 'column name' in ascending order. It works except on the initial page load.

EDIT:

tried the following, logged an empty object on page load with parameters. After clicking on a column, stateParams logged with the correct value.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, viewConfig) {
            console.log('stateParams: '+angular.toJson($stateParams));
        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not `$location.search()`, but [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#user-content-stateparams-service)

Try this:
Use DI to inject `$stateParams` into your controller and use this:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, viewConfig) {
    console.log($stateParams.column);
});
```

Also set your default route to match a url associated with a state.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/column/'Architect'/desc/true/");
```

**Additional Info:**
`$location.search()` will pull information out of the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (after the `?` in the URL), not the url pathing.

If you had `www.domain.com?column='column name'&desc=false`, then `$location.search().column` would return your value.

`$stateParams` will map the `:name` you used in the state url you made with the value that corresponds in the actual url

Comment: Hmm. My url was `www.xyz.com/index.aspx#/column/'Architect'/desc/true/`, and after injecting `$stateParams` in my controller, and console logging, it returns an empty object :(

Comment: However, after I click a column, it appears to work. Why wouldn't it work with an initial URL with parameters?

Comment: I use quotes because some columns have spaces in the name (terrible idea, not my choice). If I don't use quotes, I get errors. I'll try it on the no-space column names.

Comment: Same behavior without quotes.

Comment: Not too sure, seems like that app is not loading the initial state properly.  On your `$stateChangeSuccess`, can you log the `arguments` to ensure everything looks good at that point in the process?

Comment: $stateChangeSuccess doesn't call when the page loads, it calls when I press a column. Here is what it logged: `evt = {"name":"$stateChangeSuccess","targetScope":"$SCOPE","defaultPrevented":false,"currentScope":"$SCOPE"} toState = {"url":"/column/:column/desc/:sort/","controller":"Ctrl","name":"name"} toParams = {"column":"'Sub Pillar'","sort":"false"} fromState = {"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true} fromParams ={} `

Comment: It appears your default state is `""` not `"name"`, clicking on the `ui-sref` triggers the transition to `"name"`.  Do you have any other states besides `"name"` set up? You have an `.otherwise` pointing to a state with a url of `"/"`, but I do not see a state with that url defined.

Comment: No, name is my only state. I used `"/"` just to stay on the root page. I think that might be the issue..?

Comment: How would I set the default state? I can't seem to find any reference. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/column/'Architect'/desc/true/");` should do it for you. It will default with `'Architect'` for the column and `true` for the desc.  You can changes those to whatever you want, as long as it fits into one of the urls associated with a state.

Comment: It doesn't load the initial parameters on page load still, but you did answer my original question. Thanks for your help!